# Why does my program never run what is contained in the "else" statement?

Tags: python

The entire program runs as I expect it to. I'm trying to make hangman and the one `else` statement never runs when the `if` thing doesn't work.

```
def playGame():
    letterGuess = input("What is your guess: ")
    if letterGuess in letters:
        print("The word included", letterGuess)
    while letterGuess in letters:
        if letterGuess in letters:
            storage = letters.index(letterGuess)
            spaces.pop(storage)
            spaces.insert(storage, letterGuess)
            letters.pop(storage)
            letters.insert(storage, "-")
        else:
            usedLetters.insert(0, str(letterGuess))
            Board = Board + 1
            print(t)
    print("Wrong Letters", usedLetters)
    print(spaces)
```

Comment: `while letterGuess in letters:
        if letterGuess in letters:` because you already checked... the if thing always works...

Answer (score 1):

`while letterGuess in letters:` will only run while this is true 
since `if letterGuess in letters:` is nested inside the while it will always enter this block because it entered the while. So the else block will never be entered

Comment: Oh, hah. Now I feel like an idiot. Thanks that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are iterating through the elements of a dict using a while loop, thus every current element actually exist.
Sorry for my english, I hope you understand me.